# How to assign onChange and values to a textField inside a table using reactjs & material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Working Code : https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-snowflake-d2054?file=/src/App.js

I have an Nested Array , and I want to read the values entered inside the table , also im having a option to add new text field as well . I want to know how to assign onchange function and values to these textfields.
[image]

Also how to discard values on delete button right next to text field.

Since it is an Nested array it is becoming difficult to update values on setState.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of states with an Id property. Just use array filter by this Id on existing state and assign it back to state

Comment: how would i assign the values and onchange for the text fields ?

Comment: You have text field value={state[id]} and onchange={e => this.setState({...state, ...{id: e.target.value}}} your id could be map index or anything else

Comment: It is a nested array , so this onchange function here will not work